# <img> source not being correctly decoded in Outlook email client

Tags: php, html, image, email, outlook

I have php code that is sending email in html format and includes links to images. Gmail is interpreting the image tag source and correctly displaying the image, but Outlook converts the "/" to a "%sf" so that

```
<img src="http://54.86.198.39/API/QR_src/temp/testd170a4185cb6f6fabad9a62005b4f80e.png">
```

becomes

```
<img src="http%3a%2f%2f54.86.198.39%2fAPI%2fQR_src%2ftemp%2ftestf57d7e5f63467b171ad806a0261b095c.png">
```

Does anyone know a solution?

EDIT: highlights of the php code:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message .= "<p> <img src='http://54.86.198.39/API/QR_src/$url' /></p>";

$send = mail($target, $subject , $message, $headers);
```

Comment: show us the mail creating and sending code.

Comment: Have you tried a protocol-relative url, i.e. //54.86.198.39/API/QR_src/temp/testd170a4185cb6f6fabad9a62005b4f80e.png without the http: ? Don't know if that would make any difference but worth a try.

Comment: //54.86.198.39/API/QR_src/temp/testd170a4185cb6f6fabad9a62005b4f80e.png WORKED. How to I update to indicate the question has been answered?